# spark ETL with joins across mutilple sources

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a requirement to join 50 odd files on a set of 3 keys using spark dataframes.
I have driver table which has 100000 records per day. I left join this table with 53 other files using dataframes as follows.

```
val df1 = spark.read.parquet(<driver file>)
val df2 = spark.read.parquet(<right side file1>)
.
.
val df52 = spark.read.parquet(<right side file 52>)
//join
val refinedDF1 = df1.join(df2,Seq("key1","key2","key3"),"leftouter")).select(<some from left table>, <some from right table>)
val refinedDF2 = refinedDF1.join(df3,Seq("key1","key2","key3"),"leftouter")).select(<some from left table>, <some from right table>)
 .
 .
 so on for all 50 odd files
 refinedFinalDF.write.parquet(<s3 location>)
```

the execution fails with error

> Container exited with a non-zero exit code 52

Which is basically an outofmemory exception.
I have a fairly large cluster for a data set of 100,000 records. I have an EMR with 12 executors with 16G each and driver memory of 20G.

I have tried partitioning the data frames manually to 200 partitions with df.repartition(200) in round robin fashion and it did not help at all. Among the join keys, only key1 is distinct for all of the records and key2 and key3 are the same values for all records.
Is there any optimization that can be done to make it work?
The final dataframe I am trying to save has 140+ columns in it.
If driver table has n records then after each left outer I end up with n records only.

Update: 
I have tried creating a smaller dataframe out of driver table with limit(100) and I still get the out of memory exception.

Comment: Have you double checked that your executors are actually getting allocated 16G using the spark UI?  There are numerous ways to set those and it's easy to get wrong.  Also, did you set the appropriate yarn settings to ensure it allows containers of the size you are allocating?  Spark will add some overhead, so you need to allow larger than 16GB containers in yarn.

Comment: Hi Ryan, yes I have tried those variations and verified the memory allocation in spark executors. I have even bumped up executor overhead memory to no avail. The fact that it fails even for a small subset of records from driver say 10 records points to some fundamental problem. The same etl operation of 50+ joins  works perfectly fine on hive using tez with default yarn settings!!

Comment: Yeah.. that is weird.  Normally I would guess something causing data explosion like a cartesian join for these symptoms.  Probably the next thing I would check would be going through the executor logs carefully to see if there is more detail on why the container exited somewhere.  Maybe running on a 1 or 2 node cluster to reduce the number of logs you need to read through.  It also might be worth experimenting to figure out how many joins causes it to fail.  10? 25? only all 50?

Comment: i am using EMR. I have checked all the files involved for duplicates on join keys and there are none. So cartesian join is not an issue here. I have also tried it on 2 different emr clusters with the same problem. It randomly fails on a 20th or 30th join. My unit test which has 5 records works perfectly on my PC in spark local mode but the same load fails on the cluster for say 10 records.

Answer (score 0):

Are your tables 1-1 or 1-many?  If they are one to many, then your joins are going to result in many more rows than you probably want.  If this is the case, one option is to first do a groupBy on each table you are going to join in.  Consider this example:

```
val df1 = Seq(1, 2).toDF("id")
val df2 = Seq(
  (1, "a", true),
  (1, "b", false),
  (2, "c", true)
).toDF("id", "C2", "B2")

val df3 = Seq(
  (1, "x", false),
  (1, "y", true),
  (2, "z", false)
).toDF("id", "C3", "B3")

// Left outer join without accounting for 1-Many relationship.  Results in cartesian
// joining on each ID value!
df1.
  join(df2, Seq("id"), "left_outer").
  join(df3, Seq("id"), "left_outer").show()

+---+---+-----+---+-----+
| id| C2|   B2| C3|   B3|
+---+---+-----+---+-----+
|  1|  b|false|  y| true|
|  1|  b|false|  x|false|
|  1|  a| true|  y| true|
|  1|  a| true|  x|false|
|  2|  c| true|  z|false|
+---+---+-----+---+-----+
```

Alternatively, if you group the rows before the join so your relationship is always 1-1, you won't get records being addded

```
val df2Grouped = df2.groupBy("id").agg(collect_list(struct($"C2", $"B2")) as "df2")
val df3Grouped = df3.groupBy("id").agg(collect_list(struct($"C3", $"B3")) as "df3")

val result = df1.
  join(df2Grouped, Seq("id"), "left_outer").
  join(df3Grouped, Seq("id"), "left_outer")
result.printSchema
result.show(10, false)

scala> result.printSchema
root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- df2: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- C2: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- B2: boolean (nullable = false)
 |-- df3: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- C3: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- B3: boolean (nullable = false)


scala> result.show(10, false)
+---+-----------------------+-----------------------+
|id |df2                    |df3                    |
+---+-----------------------+-----------------------+
|1  |[[a, true], [b, false]]|[[x, false], [y, true]]|
|2  |[[c, true]]            |[[z, false]]           |
+---+-----------------------+-----------------------+
```

Comment: thanks for taking some time out to explain with details but unfortunately it is a 1 to 1 mapping for all left outer joins.. If driver table has n records then after each left outer I end up with n records only. I even tried running my etl for a small data size of 100 records , it still fails with outofmemory error.

Answer (score 0):

it so happens, the underlying data in s3 bucket  which i use to create dataframe has multiple folders in it and i was filtering for a specific folder as part of my filter. example : spark.read.parquet(s3 bucket).filter('folder_name="val"). Looks like spark is loading all of the data in s3 bucket into executor memory and then runs the filter. that is why it was bombing where as the same logic run as a hive query running on a hive external table pointing to s3 location with folder as partition column was working just fine. I had to remove the filter and read the specific folder to resolve the problem.. spark.read.parquet(s3 bucket/folder=value)..

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar condition where i had multiple joins and at the end I had to write final dataframe to HDFS/Hive Table(Parquet Format).

Spark works on Lazy Execution mechanism that means, when your 53'rd dataframe is actioned(Save/Write as Parquet), Spark then goes back to all the joins and executes them, which causes huge shuffling of data and eventually your job's containers fail and throw out of memory errors.

Suggestion: You can write every joined dataframe first onto HDFS, what I mean to say is that once you have joined 2 (can be more than 2 but keep it limited) dataframes , write the the joined dataframe to HDFS/Hive and use `select * 'hive parquet table`

```
val refinedDF1 = df1.join(df2 ,condition,'join_type')
refinedDF1.write.parquet("location") or refinedDF1.write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("dbname.refine1")
val refinedDF1 = hc.sql("select * from dbname.refine1")

val refinedDF2 = refinedDF1.join(df3)
refinedDF2.write.parquet("location") or refinedDF1.write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("dbname.refine2")
val refinedDF2 = hc.sql("select * from dbname.refine2")
```

Now you're writing your joins frequently to hdfs, that means spark wont have to execute them when you call the final join, it would only have to use 52'nd join output that you have saved in form of a table.

My script came down from 22 hours (Including container memory errors) to 15 to 30 (Without Memory Exception/Errors) minutes by using this methodology.

Few Tips:

1) Exclude the records where your join `key` is null, spark does not give good performance over joins that have `null = null` condition so remove them before joining dataframes

2) Use Broadcast joins when you're left dataframe is many rows and your right dataframe is a lookup or few rows.

3) You will have to clean up the intermediate dataframes you're saving in Hive/Hdfs after your script is executed.